# Why session.refresh(Object, LockMode.UPGRADE) is deprecated in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-session

My Requirement:

I am using Quartz `cron` for triggering purpose, Many triggers are running on same row but base on different column. So when trigger need to update its related column. trigger first refresh(`Session.refresh(object)`) the object belong to it(object is selected at starting of trigger) from database and then take an `UPGRADE  LOCK` at row level. if it is success on getting lock then is update column and use `session.update(object)` to update in DB. and release the lock.

What is the alternative of `session.refresh(Object, LockMode.UPGRADE)` and efficient way to avoid dirty update using hibernate ?

Why it is deprecated in hibernate ?

Comment: Usually deprecation notices reference what to use instead. Does the Hibernate documentation not do that??

Comment: Which Hibernate version you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the alternative of `session.refresh(Object, LockMode.UPGRADE)` and efficient way to avoid dirty update using hibernate ?

Right there in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#refresh(java.lang.Object,%20org.hibernate.LockMode)):

> **Deprecated**. `LockMode` parameter should be replaced with `LockOptions`

E.g., use [`refresh(Object,LockOptions)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#refresh(java.lang.Object,%20org.hibernate.LockOptions)).

It doesn't say *why*, but it's clear about what to do instead. (And there is a [`LockOptions.UPDATE`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/LockOptions.html#UPGRADE).)